# Multi page scanning twain using asp net framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, twain

I have windows service self-hosted application that allow you to scan files or media through twain scan driver.
Can someone help me to scan multi page file using ntwain nuget package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps:

1. Create a RESTful service and host it as a Windows service on the
   workstation where scanner is installed.
2. Implement a Get API to return scanned
   pages. Remember that the API does not return immediately and rather waits on an AutoResetEvent (See C# reference on
   AutoResetEvent)
3. NTwain triggers DataTransferred() event when all
   pages have been scanned. Raise a AutoResetEvent from within
   DataTransferred() event or SourceDisabled() event. You will need to
   override these two event. NTwain samples provide information on how
   to override.